# ComboBox и LiveBindings

Tags: delphi

Задача такая - firemonkey, нужно чтобы данные одного столбца выводились в combobox через livebindings, вроде просто, но правильные описания данной вещи отсутствуют. Нашел решение данной проблемы, нужна помощь в переводе по этой ссылке [TDBLookupCombobox FireMonkey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10211668/tdblookupcombobox-firemonkey).

Comment: что-то мне подсказывает, что тебя сейчас минусовать начнут...

Comment: Это еще почему? Попробуйте это сделать именно в delphi xe2 и именно в проекте firemonkey. В старых версиях delphi проблем не было, а сейчас все через livebindings. Причем связывание через livebindings отличается от VCL.

Comment: это ты мне предлагаешь сделать? =) где твой вопрос? что у тебя не получается? что ты делал? или ты просто поделился информацией, о том что описания данной вещи отсутствуют? спасибо, пиши лучше на твиттер...

Comment: Положил на форму adoconnection, datasource,bindscopedb связал их, положил combobox, создал для него livebindings, control указал combobox, source указал bindscopedb1, т.к. связь была dblink, то в bindingslist появилась связь где control expression - selectedtext(self) а source expression - displaytext. При запуске открывает combobox, причем количество записей в нем соответствует количеству в бд, но не выводит текст, только пустые строки.

Comment: @Gorets я бы вас заминусовал, да жаль, нельзя.  
@Serg00000 попробуйте поискать информацию о firemonkey на [этом][1] ресурсе.

[1]: http://www.webdelphi.ru/

Comment: Спасибо, был и там. По моему уже весь ру инет облазил с этим livebindings, да и не только ру.

Comment: Заказал на озоне delphi xe2 Осипова, да судя по содержанию там о livebindings страниц 20 от силы.

Comment: > весь ру инет облазил

Первая ошибка.

Answer (score 1):

перевод статьи (дословный, не промт. некоторые слова не стал переводить, так как не надо это). ControlExpressions можно понимать, как те значения, которые мы имеем в результате, а SourceExpressions - это исходные значения, которые мы выжимаем из таблиц.

Я не знаю, есть ли здесь инструкция получше, но вот как это делаю я:

Предположим у вас есть Таблица1 и внешний ключ к Таблице2.

- Сделайте искомое поле в Таблице1 внешним ключом
- Используйте **TBindList**, чтобы заполнить свойство **Text** компонента **ComboBox** из необходимого поля Таблицы2, и заполните свойство **Tag** основным ключом Таблицы2
- Используйте **TBindPosition** чтобы сравнить выбранный текст с искомым полем и **Selected.Tag** с внешним ключом к Таблице1

Проверьте свойство **SourceComponent** ваших **TBindList** и **TBindPosition**.
**TBindList** должен указывать на **BindScopeDB** Таблицы2.
**TBindPosition** взамен **BindScopeDB** Таблицы1.

**ControlComponent** должен указывать на ваш **TComboBox**

Когда вы используете **TBindList**, формируемый набор записей относится к одному объекту внутри **ComboBox**, потому что для заполнения пробегается каждая строка Таблицы2. Поэтому для **ControlExpressions** вам нужны свойства : **Text** и **Tag**.
*Заметка*: Вам не нужно свойство **Selected**

а это SourceExpressions:

```
FieldByName(LookedUpField).AsString, FieldByName(PK).AsInteger
```

Добавьте эти выражения в формируемый набор записей.

**TBindPosition** всегда относится ко всему набору объектов **ComboBox**, поэтому вам надо использовать свойство **Selected**.

ControlExpressions:

```
Selected.Tag SelectedText(Self)
```

SourceExpressions:

```
FieldByName(FK).AsInteger, FieldByName(LookupField).AsString
```

Запомните, что набор **PosSource** используется для присвоений "ControlExpressions к SourceExpressions", когда **PosControl** содержит присваивания "SourceExpressions к ControlExpressions".

Изначално вам нужно две вещи: изменять выбранный объект, когда меняется позиция в Таблице1 и заставить ваш **FK** (не знаю, что это) использовать свойство **Tag** выбранного объекта, когда пользователь его меняет.

Так что просто положите это в ваш набор **PosControl**

```
SelectedText(Self)
FieldByName(LookupField).AsString
```

А это будет в вашем наборе **PosSource**

```
Selected.Tag
FieldByName(FK).AsInteger
```

Если вы хотите получить похожее поведение компонента **TDBLookupComboBox** вам надо установить Таблицу в состояние редактирования, когда в комбобоксе меняется выбранный объект.

================================
и ключевая фраза:
For more informations look for the examples included with XE2.

Comment: Спасибо за перевод! Все равно где то не так, комбик открывается, но не выводит данные, только пустые поля.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно использовать BindList и если нужно менять положение курсора в DataSet еще BindPosition.

1. В BindList два раза тыкаем на него, заходим в Format в Control Self.Text, в Source AsString. В самом BindList указываем имя контрола и имя источника и поле откуда брать данные для заполнения.
2. В BindPosition два раза тыкаем, заходим в PosControl - в Control - ItemIndex, в Source - RecNo-1; в PosSource - в Control - ItemIndex+1, в Source - RecNo; и последнее PosClear - в Control - ItemIndex, в Source - -1.